# What's the need of importing native php functions whith `use`?

Tags: php, namespaces

Why in zend-mail there is an import of native php function: 'in_array' ?

> namespace Zend\Mail\Header;
>
> use function in_array;

Comment: yeah not sure.. that doesn't seem right ...

Comment: to me too, as it's a native function i see no need to import it :/

Comment: I suppose, strictly speaking, there *could* be a `Zend\Mail\Header\in_array` function - I'm guessing importing the native `in_array` function removes any possibility for ambiguity ... maybe?

Comment: @CD001, I've already checked that there is no namespaced function in_array

Comment: I can __redeclare__ any function in my own namespace.

Comment: @MaK - again, just a guess, with that `use function ....` there **never** can be a namespaced override; so it's there as a kind of failsafe. Yeah, I am clutching at straws a bit ;)

Comment: @CD001 - so i guess it's safe to just delete the import :)

Comment: @u_mulder - can't get your point :s

Comment: as phpstorm hints it would also enable some of opcode optimizations ;-)

Comment: @MaK u_mulder's comment was in response to something another used had posted (now deleted) about not being able to override protected functions. You *probably* could just delete the import, even if the core `in_array` function is used without the leading backslash (`\in_array()`) in the namespace, it'll still work - you could always try it and see ;)

Comment: @CD001 - Thx for sharing (& for explaining u_mulder's comment), i'm definitely going for a delete :)

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh - interesting point of view indeed.

Comment: Without the import, the `in_array` function needs to be checked to see if it exists in the current namespace. If it is not then PHP will fall back to the "global" namespace and look there. This adds extra lines to the opcode of the evaluated script. It is a minor but not insignificant optimization, especially if you consider how many "core functions" get used in a typical namespace project.

Comment: The import statement e.g. `use function in_array;` is often used instead of prepending with a backslash e.g. `\in_array(...);` because the backslash seems to cause too much cognitive dissonance for many devs.